# Java out of memory errors along with HTMLUnit errors in Jmeter

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, junit4, htmlunit

I'm really new here and to Java in general since I am only a QA tester. So I am going to try and make this short, I found a solution to one of the problems we have had testing a website, Testing an AJAX website using `Jmeter`. I managed to get `Jmeter` to run a `Junit` request recorded with Selenium using `HTMLunit` after compiling the Jar file needed using Maven In order to try and load test a website.

Everything runs fine until I get to a somewhat "load worthy" number of threads (we are a large enough company have multiple machines so this shouldn't be an issue if each could handle 200-300 requests) but I am getting some errors in the `Jmeter` cmd along with `CSS` errors in the `Jmeter` error console (they may not be related, but they appear at the same time) after setting the threads to 50:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid6832.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [817281280 bytes in 13.116 secs]
Logging Error: Unknown error writing event.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Logging Error: Unknown error writing event.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Logging Error: Unknown error writing event.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Logging Error: Unknown error writing event.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Logging Error: Unknown error writing event.
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2013/02/04 14:01:10 WARN  - com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler: CSS warning: 'Website URL+CSS PATH' [2447:70] Ignoring the whole rule. 
2013/02/04 14:01:10 WARN  - com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler: CSS error: 'Website URL+CSS PATH' [1684:57] Error in pseudo class or element. (Invalid token "2". Was expecting one of: <S>, <IDENT>, ")".)
```

These are the errors I get, I am guessing it is having a hard time getting the requests through (since I know `htmlunit` acts as if it was a browser and sending 100 requests at a time using that browser may be demanding too much of my current resources)

So, question is: I just wanted to make sure I was correct in assessing the problems I am seeing and also wondering if anyone has done something like this before and if maybe anyone has found a better way of handling these kinds of tests?

Comment: Having used Selenium, I would be surprised if it coped. Depending on what you are actually testing, `curl`ing lots of requests might be cheaper. The actual errors might be worth investigating in any case (the last two log lines).

Comment: It's nearly impossible to help you as you have some custom code we don't have.You should try your test from jmeter core if possible.
Why do you use html unit+ selenium ? Can you explain ?

Comment: From researching online ive seen that Jmeter doesnt really like AJAX by itself all that much

Comment: @user2040718 JMeter doesn't render the web page so AJAX isn't relevant.  At the end of the day when you are performance testing, you are just calling resources from the web server directly.  AJAX is just another request to the webserver and JMeter is quite capable of sending these requests.  It sounds like you don't quite understand JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're using JMeter in GUI mode for your load test which is an Anti-Pattern.

I guess you have View Results Tree listener in your plan, so this component ends up cumulating all results and ends with an OOM .

Since recent version of JMeter, only 500 last Sample Results are kept.

So upgrade to JMeter 4.0 or 5.0 AND use NON GUI mode:

> jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -l results.csv -e -o report_folder